# Timeout Length for Google Docs Script Triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

What is the timeout length for script triggers in Google docs?

For example I'm querying a RESTful API every minute in a script that outputs into a spreadsheet.  It usually fails a few times a day with error types of 'Timeout' and 'Address Unavailable'.

The service states that sometimes under load the API takes over 30 seconds to respond but should complete all queries within 60 seconds.

If there is a difference when the I'm concerned with the timeout for when the spreadsheet is not open by a user.

Alternatively is there a way I can change the timeout for script triggers?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the script that's timing out, but rather the UrlFetchApp request. If the server doesn't respond within 60 seconds then you'll get a "Timeout" error.